# c# to generate a list of columns from a sql query string

Tags: c#, sql

I have a simple routine that takes a `SELECT` statement and uses a `DataTable`.

I use the same `SELECT` statement and pass it through a routine to generate an array of column names and data types.

As long as the `SELECT` statement is simple

e.g `SELECT Firstname,Secondname...`etc...

... my routine can add the column information to my array

However, if the `SELECT` statement is a little more complex

e.g. `SELECT Firstname,Secondname AS Surname...` etc...

... my routine will fall over because `Surname` is not a column name.

More complexity can occur when you factor in subqueries and aggregate columns.

I am looking for a more elegant approach if there is one to acquire any base column names from a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Where does the 'routine' get the column names from? Are you using a dataadaptor to populate the datatable, in which case the columns should be fine?

Comment: As long as your DB is simple and efficient designed you can find an elegant query. If your "names" table is complicated and complex every query will have troubles getting the results..

Comment: So, you are asking how to parse an SQL Statment into a schema?

Answer (score 2):

You have a [DataTable.Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) property were every object is a [DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx), which is populated based on the query you made.

So if you used `as` inside your `SQL` syntax, you should find the same name inside that collection too.

Comment: Using my original example, **"Surname"** would get returned from the DataColumn, not **Secondname**, which is not what I need

Comment: @user2890085: don't think you can achieve this, as this is SQL syntax that generates data back to DataTable. Not very sure if there is any other property that refers to column *real* name, as from data perspective the real name is actually that one declared in "as" clause.

Comment: @user2890085: you can always execute another query that asks for real column names, but this sound kind of overkill..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69.aspx) to execute the query. Then you can use [GetName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getname.aspx) to obtain the name of each field coming back.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I should have mentioned that this is a MsAccess table, but the GetName() method will be useful if/when we port to MSSQL.

Comment: It is a member of DbDataReader, so it is DB independent actually. I update the response to reflect that, more correct in any case